# MySQL count identical values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have this table named prizes with the following structure

```
`id` (PRIMARY)
`id_multiple`
`desc`
`winner`
```

I want to select those who don't have a `winner` (`NULL`) and display them together if they have the same `id_multiple` showing the count of how many left to win of that `id_multiple`.

So for example, there's this values:

```
id_multiple | winner | desc
1           | NULL   | voucher
1           | jonh   | voucher
2           | NULL   | car
2           | NULL   | car
```

And I want to display:

```
Left to win:
1 Voucher
2 Car
```

(The `desc` will be the same for all `id_multiple` so it might be ambiguous to use `id_multiple`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT id_multiple,count(id_multiple),`desc` 
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE `winner` IS NULL
GROUP BY `id_multiple`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `count` a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   id_multiple, COUNT(CASE WHEN winner IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS left_to_win, `desc`
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id_multiple, `desc`
```

Or, even simpler, with a `sum` expression that takes advantage of the fact that `true` is interpreted as `1` and `false` as `0` in numerical contexts:

```
SELECT   id_multiple, SUM(winner IS NULL) AS left_to_win, `desc`
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id_multiple, `desc`
```